# how to crud nested relationship enum field

Tags: nested, relationship, laravel-backpack-5

I have a order and orderInfo models.
I want to do crud for orderInfo.language field from orderCrudController. Language column is Enum.
Order and orderinfo have one-to-one relationship.

I tried below

```
    $orderlanguages = getOrderLanguages();
    CRUD::addField([
        'name' => 'orderInfo.language',
        'type' => 'select_from_array',
        'options' => $orderlanguages,
        'label' => 'Language'
    ]);
```

But while updating it gives below error.
Call to undefined method App\Models\OrderInfo::getCastedAttributes()